# Trying to understand an integral algebraically and conceptually $f'(t) = \frac{Ae^t}{(0.02A+e^t)^2}$

Tags: integration, actuarial-science

It is defined that $f'(t) = \frac{Ae^t}{(0.02A+e^t)^2}$ is the rate of population.

It is also given that the population at $t=0$ is given as 6.

Our goal is to find the time $t$ where the population hits $30$.

I want to solve of the constant $A$, but I am not sure how to.

My understanding is that in order to do so, we just take the integral of $f'(t)$ and plug in $f(0)=6$, but I ended up only to find the value of the constant that results from taking any indefinite integral.

Can someone help me out ?

According to the book I have $A = 46.15$ by finding $\lim_{t \to \infty}f(t)=30$.

Which I couldn't understand conceptually why we can do so.

Comment: From the description you give, the problem may say that as $t\to\infty$, pop. approaches $30$ and wants you to find $A$.

Comment: That is true ! Thank you so much, that clarifies everything.

Comment: You are welcome. As you suspected/knew, one cannot determine the value of our function just from the initial value, since there is obvious dependence on the parameter $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

$$f(t)-f(0) = A \int_0^t dt' \frac{e^{t'}}{(0.02 A+e^{t'})^2}$$

To evaluate the integral, substitute $u=e^{t'}$ and get

$$f(t)-6 = A \int_1^{e^{t}} \frac{du}{(u+0.02 A)^2}  = A \left [\frac{1}{1+0.02 A}-\frac{1}{e^t+0.02 A} \right ]$$

Now you gave us

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t)=30$$

so that

$$30-6=24=\frac{A}{1+0.02 A} \implies 24 + \frac{12}{25} A=A \implies A = \frac{600}{13} \approx 46.15$$

Comment: Thank you ! All I really needed was why we needed to take the limit as t goes to $\infty$.